# Obtener el valor del monto devengada relacionado a cada valor de la columna Mes_EJE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día estimados, su apoyo para poder apoyarme para obtener el valor correspondiente de cada valor que se encuentra en una columna, este valor debe originar nuevas columnas:

```
select FUENTE_FINANC_NOMBRE, MES_EJE, MONTO_DEVENGADO 
from dbo.[06042021v2] 
where PRODUCTO_PROYECTO=2234988
```

Datos de ejemplo:

| Fuente_Financ_Nombre | MES_EJE | MONTO_DEVENGADO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios | 0 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 0 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24268 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24668 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24578 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24968 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 1 | 24568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 24578 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 2498 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 23568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 24568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 24568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 24568 |
| Recursos ordinarios financiamiento | 2 | 24568 |

- En la columna `MES_EJE tengo` valores 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, no se debe considerar el valor `0` de la columna `MES_EJE`
- En la columna `Monto_devengado` tengo montos asociado a cada mes

Como respuesta debería salir:

| Fuente de financimiento | Monto_devengado_Mes_1 | Monto_devengado_Mes_2 | Monto_devengado_Mes_3 | Monto_Acumulado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Recurso Ordinario Financiamiento | 1476128 | 127916 | 234567 | 1838616 |
| Fuente Financiamiento1 | 56456441 | 4564645 | 455665646 | 3939393933 |
| Fuente Financiamiento2 | 99999999 | 9999999 | 999999999 | 2292929292 |

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, no se entiende que quieres hacer. Por favor, mejora tu pregunta para obtener más ayuda.

Comment: Hola, por favor sería buena idea añadir un ejemplo del resultado que deseas esperar en base a esa consulta, así se podrá tener una idea de cuál sería la consulta (o query) a crear.

Comment: No veo forma de llegar al resultado que buscas con los datos que pones de ejemplo... no coinciden ni los montos, ni las descripciones. Creo que debes explicar cuál es el proceso que seguirías manualmente para llegar a ese resultado con esos datos, solo después de entender bien ese proceso se podría escribir un query o rutina que lo arroje.

Answer (score 0):

Esta query retorna el resultado esperado: agrupa por fuente de financiamiento y muestra el total por mes devengado (1 mes por columna) y el total acumulado del año.

```
SEELCT FUENTE_FINANC_NOMBRE, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 1 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 2 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 3 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_3,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 4 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_4,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 5 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_5,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 6 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_6,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 7 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_7,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 8 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_8,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 9 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_9,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 10 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_10,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 11 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_11,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MES_EJE = 12 THEN MONTO_DEVENGADO ELSE 0 END) AS Monto_devengado_Mes_12,
   SUM(MONTO_DEVENGADO) AS Monto_Acumulado
FROM dbo.[06042021v2] 
WHERE PRODUCTO_PROYECTO = 2234988 AND MES_EJE > 0
GROUP BY FUENTE_FINANC_NOMBRE
```

Si MONTO_DEVENGADO puede tener valores nulos, entonces tendrás que usar la funicón ISNULL() en cada lugar donde aparezca sumado: `ISNULL(MONTO_DEVENGADO, 0)`.